# Update multiple rows in table from sql export file

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to update the table `api_hotspot`'s existing rows according to the data I've exported from another table on a different database.  For each tuple in the export I want to set the fields address=tuple[1], LAT=tuple[2], LNG=tuple[3] on the row who's id=tuple[0], but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

```
UPDATE `api_hotspot` SET `LAT`=[2],`LNG`=[3],`address`=[1] WHERE id = [0] VALUES
(9, '272 College St S #9, Monmouth, OR 97361, USA', 44.846668, -123.239334),
(11, '169 Main St W, Monmouth, OR 97361, USA', 44.848419, -123.236961),
(12, '1103 Goucher St, Amity, OR 97101, USA', 45.111313, -123.199585),
(13, '380 Pacific Ave N, Monmouth, OR 97361, USA', 44.851665, -123.229607),
(14, '2410 NW Burnside Ct. Gresham, OR, 97030', 0.000000, 0.000000),
...
```

How can I do this without using regex to replace each line manually?

```
UPDATE `api_hotspot` SET `LAT`=44.846668,`LNG`=-123.239334,`address`='272 College St S #9, Monmouth, OR 97361, USA' WHERE id = 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data into a table e.g. `export (id, address, lat, lng)` and do an update with a join

```
UPDATE api_hotspot
LEFT JOIN export ON export.id = api_hotspot.id
SET api_hotspot.address = export.address, api_hotspot.lat = export.lat, api_hotspot.lng = export.lng
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that didn't involve creating a new table, because I wanted to automate it with a script that would replace the top of the export file with the proper code, but it appears making a table and doing a join is the only way to do this.

Comment: No one says the table needs to be permanent, you can create a `TEMPORARY` table or delete the created table afterwards. Both can be easily done in a script.